# How to prove the existence of source node in directed graph at each step of topological sorting

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm trying to prove that in a directed graph without directed cycles, removing a source causes the creation of another source. For example, when applying [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on a graph, after we remove a source from graph $G$, we have more sources in the newly generated graph $G'$ that perhaps didn't exist in $G$.

I tried to prove it using the fact that after the removal of source $r$, all the vertices must have at least a degree of 1, and to somehow show that it implies that before the removal of $r$, there were directed cycles, but I'm having trouble completing the proof. Perhaps anyone has an idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Every directed acyclic graph (DAG) contains a source - for example, the vertex that comes first in a topological order. Since the removal of a vertex from a DAG leaves a DAG, there must exist a source after the vertex-removal.

It is not true, however, that "removing a source causes the creation of another source". For example, if the graph was empty, removing a vertex can not create new sources, since every vertex was a source to begin with.